# SD card not detected

Tags: linux, data-recovery, sd-card, file-recovery

I have a SD card with photos I'd like to recover. The card suddenly stopped working in camera, maybe because of the temperatures like 40C outside. The camera can't read the card and advises to use another one. Two different laptops with linux and windows can't detect it at all. I've  used internal laptop card readers.

I've tried:

- fdisk -l, lsblk, blkid but they don't show the card
- dmesg outputs nothing after inserting/taking out
- dd if=/dev/sdb of=dump conv=noerror gives: no medium found
- dosfsck, kpartx gives: no medium found
- gdisk -l gives: Problem opening /dev/sdb for reading! Error is 123
- chkdsc gives: cannot open volume for direct access
- testdisc, photorec can't work as I can't indicate the medium

I'm out of ideas, can you help me?

Comment: The card seems broken.

Comment: If so, what can I do by myself to get data from it?